# Need to add some padding-top on a placeholder of a text area

Tags: css, placeholder

I know about how to stylize the placeholder from here [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/)

But I need to know about how to apply to a specific text area.My text-area has class "message".

Thanks.

Actually I used padding.But was interested about thee styling of placeholder with a css3 seelctor.

any help?

Comment: please share your code (HTML and CSS)

Comment: OP, please see my latest edit, i understand what you're after now

Comment: Because you got the answer from me.

Comment: @Gezzasa not the situation at all, please check your notification

Answer (score 7):

All you need is `.message { padding-top: 10px; }` to achieve the result you're after.

It will apply to any `<textarea>` that has the class of `message`

**EDIT**

If you don't want to apply padding to the element, try this instead. It literally *just* targets the `placeholder`.

```
.message::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   padding-top: 10px;
}

.message::-moz-input-placeholder {
   padding-top: 10px;
}

.message:-moz-input-placeholder {
   padding-top: 10px;
}

.message:-ms-input-placeholder {
   padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Can be seen in action here, I set up 2 `<textarea>`'s to show this - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/tan7k4rf/

Comment: Sorry @Gezzasa, no i honestly just wanted to add this to it, i didnt realise yours was the same after you edited the color out. I was just concentrating on my own answer

Comment: not a problem, thank you. It just looked a bit suspect to me. I guess the notifications come in a little late. Apologies.

Answer (score 3):

This what you are looking for?

```
<textarea  placeholder="Placeholder text!" class="message"></textarea>
<textarea  placeholder="Placeholder text!" ></textarea>

.message::-webkit-input-placeholder {padding-top: 10px;}
.message:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */padding-top: 10px;}
.message::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */padding-top: 10px;}
.message:-ms-input-placeholder {padding-top: 10px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/92gnt7qt/3/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: So all you want to do is add padding to it?

.message {padding-top: 10px}

Comment: It's not my question, but the OP wants padding-top, which is stated in the title. Also, 10px isn't specified by the OP, it's an amount i chose to exhibit how the code will work

Comment: And to clarify, my original answer did answer his question.

"But was interested about thee styling of placeholder with a css3 seelctor.

any help?"

My answer showed how to style a specific placeholder with a class of message. With that he could have changed the 'color:red' to whatever he needed it to be.

Comment: @AndyHolmes Why would you edit your answer after mine with the correct info?

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS:

```
textarea {
    padding-top: 14px;
    font-size: 1.0rem;
}

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

textarea::-moz-placeholder {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

textarea::-ms-input-placeholder {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply CSS for that class...

```
.message{padding-top:10px;}
```

Or

```
padding:10px;
```

If you want to apply padding on all sides

AND apply it to text area:

```
<textarea class="message"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try this .Its working Fine and Tested  !!!

```
<body>
<textarea placeholder = "Enter Your Stuff Here !! Area" class "message"></textarea>
</body>
```

And you can Add css to class as Follows:

```
.message  {
    padding-top : 12px;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Give your text area an ID and use that to assign css rules.

e.g.

(html)

```
<textarea id="thisOne" style="message">
```

(css)

```
#thisOne -moz-placeholder {
   padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: while this is fine, using an ID to target a specific text area, there's no need for `-moz-`. Also, utilising the class is better